# How to stop looping a program once a condition has been met

Tags: python, python-3.2

So I decided to write a program to see how long it takes for a level 2 dark elixir drill to produce more than a level 1 in Clash of Clans. It takes two days to upgrade, so the level 1 gets two days worth of dark elixir head start.

My question is, how can I make the loop stop (or how to use a different loop) that stops once second > first?

```
hour = 0
first = 960
second = 0
days = 0
while True:
    hour = hour + 4
    if hour - 24 >= 0:
        hour = hour - 24
        days = days + 1
    else:
        hour = hour
    first = first + 80
    second = second + 120
    if first >= second:
        print("After", days, "days and", hour, "hours, a level 1 produces", first, "dark elixir, while a level 2 produces", second, "dark elixir!")
    else:
        print("After", days, ",", hour, "hours, a level 2 produces more dark elixir than a level one!")
```

What's happening now is it's printing the else statement, but it's updating days and hour variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
if first >= second:
    print("After", days, "days and", hour, "hours, a level 1 produces", first, "dark elixir, while a level 2 produces", second, "dark elixir!")
else:
    print("After", days, ",", hour, "hours, a level 2 produces more dark elixir than a level one!")
    break
```

The break statement terminates the nearest enclosing loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
while second < first:
    # exactly the same code
```